# Input boxes disable/enable box when there is form specified

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to get form in table with enabling and disabling inputs by checkbox.
When I realized, that `<form>` is not working in tables I put `form` argument in inputs, but now disabling/enabling doesn't working (my js skill is kinda poor)

My checkbox to disable/enable inputs look like:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.elements['bleh'].disabled = this.form.elements['bleh2'].disabled = !this.checked" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edytuj"/>
</td>
```

And my input boxes for now are:

```
<td><input type="text" name="bleh" form="id7" value="default" disabled=disabled></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bleh2" form="id7" value="admin" disabled=disabled></td>
```

Comment: Best would be just javascript without any additional libs or functions (just in "onclick" if it's possible).
Btw this "onclick" is a bit longer (disabling/enabling 7 elements)

Comment: Why not just give the inputs ids and then use `getElementById` method in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you give your form a name you can reach the elements like this:

```
document.FORM_NAME.ELEMENT_NAME.disable
```

Eg

```
document.id7.bleh.disabled
```

So you can change your onclick to

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="document.id7.bleh.disabled = document.id7.bleh2.disabled = !this.checked" />
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/48xcw/2/)

[Using form attribute to external form](http://jsfiddle.net/48xcw/4/)

Comment: @jan0s1k [Check the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uB2Nd/1/) `form="id7"` ***adds element to the form with id7***, you need to specify `<form id="id7">`

Comment: It's because you haven't set the form attribute on some of the inputs - you also need to add an id to the actual form too for the form tag to work properly - http://jsfiddle.net/uB2Nd/3/

Comment: Ok, `id` attribute made it working, big thanks guys for help ;)

@Pete not all have to be possible to edit, it's for updating mysql table.

Comment: You would still need to apply the form attribute to the inputs otherwise their values won't get submitted with the form - even if you don't want them editable (just don't set the disabled in the onclick)

Comment: Yes, I know, I'll set `readonly` attribute for these, but thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

***[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/QFF6m/1/)***

1. When you have your **table within the form**

   > `<form action="#">
   >           <table>
   >               <tr>
   >                   <td>
   >                       <input type="text" name="bleh" value="default" disabled="disabled" />
   >                   </td>
   >                   <td>
   >                       <input type="text" name="bleh2" value="admin" disabled="disabled" />
   >                   </td>
   >                   <td>
   >                       <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form['bleh'].disabled = this.form['bleh2'].disabled = !this.checked" />
   >                       <input type="submit" value="Edytuj" />
   >                   </td>
   >               </tr>
   >           </table>
   >      </form>`
2. When you declare your form **elements outside the form**

   > `<table>
   >           <tr>
   >               <td>
   >                   <input type="text" name="bleh" form="id7" value="default" disabled="disabled" />
   >               </td>
   >               <td>
   >                   <input type="text" name="bleh2" form="id7" value="admin" disabled="disabled" />
   >               </td>
   >               <td>
   >                   <input type="checkbox" onclick="document.forms['id7']['bleh'].disabled = document.forms['id7']['bleh2'].disabled = !this.checked" />
   >                   <input type="submit" value="Edytuj" />
   >               </td>
   >           </tr>
   >       </table>
   >      <form name="id7" id="id7" action="#"></form>`